Question about working with .NET MAUI Calendar (SfCalendar)

Is it possible to somehow hide the days and numbers of the previous and future month in the calendar for a month? To display only the numbers of the selected month in the month.
I have not found this solution in the documentation, perhaps it can be done in some other way? Thanks in advance for the answer!

try setting ShowTrailingAndLeadingDates

Well, as a wiki answer, according to Jason.

Is it possible to somehow hide the days and numbers of the previous and future month in the calendar for a month? To display only the numbers of the selected month in the month.

You can refer to the doc: Month cell appearance using DataTemplate. Setting ShowTrailingAndLeadingDates to False can hide the days and numbers of the previous and future month in the calendar for a month.

You can use it..
OtherMonthDayColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray300}}"
OtherMonthDayIsVisible="True"
Working Perfectly
